# Why relative path path does not display HTML5 subtitles

Tags: html, relative-path, absolute-path, webvtt

Yesterday I started working with [HTML5  Autoplay](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) and also adding [HTML5  Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_track.asp) aka Subtitles.

I am having trouble to understand why when I am playing a sample of an *.mp4 video it can display the subtitles through the relative path (file:///Users/user/Desktop/test.html) but if I execute the file through the Pycharm for example it produces this file path (http://localhost:63343/Desktop/test.html) on the browser and it loads the subtitles just fine.

So I am wondering if there is a way to solve my problem. How can I load the subtitles through the absolute path (file:///Users/user/Desktop/test.html). Is there something that I am missing here?

I am using google-chrome as a web browser.

**Update:** I was trying to debug my web page and I got the same error as [Crossorigin errors when loading VTT file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256830/crossorigin-errors-when-loading-vtt-file). Where same people say that they were able to solve this problem by [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome). I tried restarting my browser with the following way (`open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security`) but it did not had any difference on my problem.

**Update 2:** I just tested the same problem on alternative browser Safar (Version 9.0.2 (11601.3.9)). On Safari I am able to see the subtitles with the (file:///Users/user/Desktop/test.html) and with (http://localhost:63343/Desktop/test.html) the video is not displayed.

With Google-Chrome (Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit)) I can play the video both ways but I can only see the subtitles with (http://localhost:63343/Desktop/test.html).

Further search on the web helped me to find [CORS settings attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes) where the user can set crossOrigin property either to (anonymous) or (use-credentials). I also tried that, the result was black screen in video.

So in conclusion I believe is a security issue and not a path file issue.

Sample of test.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample of video with vtt file</title>
</head>
<body>
<video id="video" controls preload="metadata" width="350" height="250" autoplay>
    <source src="SampleVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="SampleVideo.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="subtitles-en.vtt" default>
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample of subtitles-en.vtt file code:

```
WEBVTT

Introduction
00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:02.000
Wikipedia is a great adventure. It may have
its shortcomings, but it is the largest collective
knowledge construction endevour

Disclaimer
00:00:02.000 --> 00:00:05.000
This is just a track demo using VTT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have solved it yourself, but you are correct, it is indeed a security issue in that you cannot access files on the local filesystem that way.

Comment: I am open to any suggestions, is there any other way?

Comment: Do you need to load them this way? Can it not run on a webserver?

Comment: This is a good question, but the reason that I want to test them locally is because I am planning to save them also locally on an android device. So unfortunately they need to be able to run locally.

Comment: Hmm, I see your point. I am not sure how this can be done. Google search time!