# <track> Unsafe attempt to load URL () from frame with URL ()

Tags: html

```
watch.html:1 Unsafe attempt to load URL file:///C:/subtitle.vtt from frame with URL file:///C:/watch.html. 'file:' URLs are treated as unique security origins.
```

This is the error I get in Chrome's console when attempting to add the subtitle to the video. The subtitle is working on Internet Explorer without any error message. The code I'm running:

```
<video controls>
<source src="C:\video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<track src="C:\subtitle.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="English">
</video>
```

Comment: Firefox and Chrome security standards are strict. IE is on its way to out for good. If you have a website, test it from there. If you try testing it locally from your browser or from an iframe of a site such SO, Chrome and Firefox will block it.

Comment: You sholdn't have problems with chrome to use track if the version of chrome you're using is 18.0 or greater. Maybe it's because of the path you're using. W3 specification for html path are an url(like ```http://example/example```) when they are absolute paths, or something like  ```/example``` when they're relative. You could try doing ```src="subtitle.vtt"```. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Comment: @ezluci AFAIK the `.vtt` must be ran on a webpage from a server. Install [LAMP](http://www.ampps.com/LAMP) server.

Comment: Do you still have the issue ? if you found a workaround in the meantime you could post it as a solution here.

Comment: Is there a solution when is not in the same path? IE: video hosted in AWS s3?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crossorigin errors when loading VTT file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256830/crossorigin-errors-when-loading-vtt-file)

Answer (score 3):

Solution: The video and subtitle file should be in the same path!

Comment: Could you specify what this mean? Aren't the video and subtitle already in the same path in the question? `src="C:\video.mp4"` and `src="C:\subtitle.vtt"`

Comment: @PinyiWang: I assume, that if they are in the same path, you should have no need to specify the (same) path again, but simply refer to "subtitle.vtt".

Comment: not working in chrome

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding of [CORSRequestNotHttp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp):

> #### Loading a local file
>
> Local files from the same directory and subdirectories were
> historically treated as being from the [same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). This meant that a
> file and all its resources could be loaded from a local directory or
> subdirectory during testing, without triggering a CORS error.
>
> Unfortunately this had security implications, as noted in this
> advisory: [CVE-2019-11730](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2019-21/#CVE-2019-11730). Many browsers, including Firefox and Chrome,
> now treat all local files as having opaque origins (by default). As a
> result, loading a local file with included local resources will now
> result in CORS errors.

The only fix today is to set up a local server:

> Developers who need to perform local testing should now set up a local
> server. As all files are served from the same scheme and domain
> (localhost) they all have the same origin, and do not trigger
> cross-origin errors.