# Captions / Subtitles not working with video tag LWC

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-s3, salesforce-lightning

I'm trying to show subtitles / captions in the video tag that I've embedded in my HTML file. However, the captions don't show at all.

HTML:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src={videoUrl} type="video/mp4">
    <track src={myTrackFileUrl} kind="captions" srclang="en">
</video>
```

JS:

```
connectedCallback() {
    this.videoUrl = 'xyz.amazonaws.com/myVideoPath';
    this.myTrackFileUrl = 'myTrackFileUrl'; //I earlier used xyz.amazonaws.com/myTrackFileUrl
}
```

Earlier, I was getting unsafe attempt to load url domains protocols and ports must match srt file html video tag "same path" error when I was supplying the full url to the track src(captionFileUrl) and once I changed it to above as per answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59581827/track-unsafe-attempt-to-load-url-from-frame-with-url) it stopped throwing this error in console but captions are still not showing in video. I've tried using both webvtt and srt files for track and none of them seem to be working.

I also tried setting the track mode to showing like below but even this does not have any effect.

```
renderedCallback() {
    this.template.querySelectorAll('video').forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('load', () => {
            let tracks = item.textTracks[0];
            tracks.mode = 'showing';  
        })
    })
}
```

Has anyone encountered such issue? Any help would be much appreciated.

I have tried different combinations but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: What is the format of your subtitle file? Is it `*.vtt`?

Comment: Yes, I copied a sample file from mozilla docs and it doesn't work.. I even tried using srt file but that doesn't work either..

Comment: Try this - open the developer console of your browser, and go to the Network tab. Once there, mark the `Media` and `Other` resource type, and see if that filters out everything but the video and subtitle file. If they're both there, check if there are any errors in the console - for example security errors.